# HTML entity decode java

Tags: java, php, regex

What is Java equivalent of `html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`
in PHP.
Example:

This is my Text,

```
Mivan is an aluminium formwork system developed by a European construction company. In 1990, the Mivan Company Ltd. from Malaysia started manufacturing these formwork systems. Today, more than 30,000sqm of formwork from Mivan Co. Ltd. 

Advantages:

· More seismic resistance

· Increased durability

· Lesser number of joints and reduced leakages

· Higher carpet area
```

The required Format is:

```
Mivan is an aluminium formwork system developed by a European construction company. In 1990, the Mivan Company Ltd. from Malaysia started manufacturing these formwork systems. Today, more than 30,000sqm of formwork from Mivan Co. Ltd. Advantages: · More seismic resistance · Increased durability · Lesser number of joints and reduced leakages .Higher carpet area.
```

Using the following regular expression in java to remove spaces/tabs/new lines doesn't work

```
comment=comment.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
comment=comment.replaceAll("\t\n\r", "");
```

Comment: What does that have to do with HTML entities? Does the code contain any html entities?

Comment: That's not the text you gave in your example. Can you edit your question and write the *actual* text that you have troubles with, the result you really expect, the code that you are using and the result that this code produces that you don't like? And by the way, isn't the relevant PHP command `strip_tags` rather than `html_entity_decode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace one or more line breaks with a single space.

```
String s ="Mivan is an aluminium formwork system developed by a European construction company. In 1990, the Mivan Company Ltd. from Malaysia started manufacturing these formwork systems. Today, more than 30,000sqm of formwork from Mivan Co. Ltd. \n" + 
            "\n" + 
            "Advantages:\n" + 
            "\n" + 
            "· More seismic resistance\n" + 
            "\n" + 
            "· Increased durability\n" + 
            "\n" + 
            "· Lesser number of joints and reduced leakages\n" + 
            "\n" + 
            "· Higher carpet area";
String comment = s.replaceAll("[\\n\\r]+", " ");
System.out.println(comment);
```

**Output:**

```
Mivan is an aluminium formwork system developed by a European construction company. In 1990, the Mivan Company Ltd. from Malaysia started manufacturing these formwork systems. Today, more than 30,000sqm of formwork from Mivan Co. Ltd.  Advantages: · More seismic resistance · Increased durability · Lesser number of joints and reduced leakages · Higher carpet area
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to replace all white-spaces with a single space:

```
comment = comment.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```